# Vundle load plugins while still in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vundle

I'm trying to create my first own `.vimrc` file. I'm having some trouble when trying to load plugins with Vundle. For example, I want to use `vim-airline`, so I have (in the correct place I believe) in my `.vimrc` file this:

```
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
```

I installed them using `:PluginInstall` succesfully.  However, when I try to set the theme for the airline plugin, using in my `.vimrc`:

```
AirlineTheme luna
```

It doesn't work; vim says on startup `E492: Not an editor command: AirlineTheme luna`. When I continue and manually do `:AirlineTheme luna` while vim is running, it works. So for some reason, I can't use any commands provided by the plugins in the `.vimrc` file. What do I do wrong, or how do I circumvent this issue?

For reference, here is a stripped version of my `.vimrc`:

```
" ====== Load Plugins ======
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required

filetype off                  " required
" Set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" Vundle manages itself
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
" Add other plugins to Vundle
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on


" ======= Allow for project specific .vimrc files =======
set exrc
set secure


" ====== Configure Plugins  ======

" Airline Theme
set laststatus=2
AirlineTheme luna
```

Note that it is the very last line that does not work.

Comment: Since this is your first vimrc, do yourself a favor and choose a different plugin manager.  Just about any other would do, f.i. NeoBundle, VAM, Plug.  Even Pathogen.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Any reason? I am using Vundle and it seems very easy and nice... It just does all the work for you...

Answer (score 1):

That command from the plugin is not available, until sourcing the vimrc is actually done. So either explicitly set the theme using `let g:airline_theme = 'luna'` which is the documented way to set your airline theme, or wrap your command into an VimEnter autocommand.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to fix it using this:

```
let g:airline_theme = 'luna'
```

For now, I'll assume that the commands created by plugins are not available in your `.vimrc` file itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing your .vimrc file and want to load/ attempt to load it you can just run `:so %`

Here is a link to another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/132030/237154) that explains this further.